# Disable public access to my apache2 server

Tags: apache2, webserver

I've just installed apache2 on my Ubuntu 14.04

My server is now accessible from anywhere if the right IP was provided. I want to disable that so that only users within my local network would be able to access the server.

I presume it has to be done from `apache2.conf`

P.S. I am sure this question has been asked before, but I think I lack the correct keywords to find a previous post :)

Comment: I would just enable the firewall on the machine that is facing the Internet (whether this is your Apache server or not)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe is better to enable firewall?
UFW can allow access from host/network and deny for the rest of the world.

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/zz to any port 80 proto tcp
```

`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` - represent your local network, `zz` reprezent network mask

You can list rules with command

`sudo ufw status`

or

`sudo ufw status numbered`

Comment: works fine in ubuntu 20.04LTS

Answer (score 4):

I found it!

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Scroll down till `<Directory /var/www/>`

Add these two lines before `</Directory>`

```
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

This will deny access from any IP except `127.0.0.1`, which is your own machine. If your network's IP is in the form of `192.168.x.x`  then allowing access from `192.168.` will allow access to anyone in your network.